# Property for react component is not defined

Tags: reactjs

After running this code - I got the exception that "title" is not defined. I checked that api returns correct data. And on the debug mode I noticed that render() from Idea component is running earlier than getting the data from API. Can you explain why is it working in this way? And what options I have for resolving this issue?
Thanks

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const client = require('./client');

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {map: {}};
}

componentDidMount() {
    client({method: 'GET', path: '/api/maps/1'}).done(response => {
        this.setState({map: response.entity._embedded.map});
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Map map={this.state.map}/>
    )
}
}

class Map extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="map_header">
                <AddIdeaButton></AddIdeaButton>
                <Idea idea={this.props.map.root}></Idea>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class AddIdeaButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <a id="btn_add">
            </a>
        );
    }
}

class Idea extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <div id="root">{this.props.idea.title}</div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('react')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous request for data takes some time during which React still renders `Map` and `Idea` components. You can simply render `Idea` conditionally when data is available:

```html
<div id="map_header">
    <AddIdeaButton></AddIdeaButton>
    {this.props.map.root && (
      <Idea idea={this.props.map.root}></Idea>
    )}
</div>
```